# Conflict between rxdart and get libraries

Tags: flutter, get, rxdart

I have a flutter project where i'm using get for state management and routing as well , and on the other hand i need rxdart ( combinelist2 ) to provide a duration for my music player , upon importing both libraries , there was conflict between both libraries but i got no clue on how to exclude or hide any of their components , any help would be appreciated .

- This is the conflict message

```
 The name 'Rx' is defined in the libraries 'package:get/get_rx/src/rx_types/rx_types.dart' and 'package:rxdart/src/rx.dart (via package:rxdart/rxdart.dart)'
```

Comment: how about using `as` prefix

Comment: Yes i tried to do so  , i tried as get and as rxdart but both did not resolve the conflict

Comment: not sure bt If you want to get specific method, you can also use `show`, Can you include a sample snippet that will produce this issue

Comment: Yeah since the get library includes rxdart , therefore when i added rxdart itself as library independently , it showed the conflict , basically i thought about excluding rxdart from get but did not succeed ..

Comment: I solved it mate : rxdart.Rx.combineLatest2<Duration, PlaybackEvent, DurationState> and import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart' as rxdart;

Comment: yap `as` prefix works

Comment: Not only that make sure to add rxdart.Rx... as well to refer to that import , thank you for your time mate